# Mocking a promise inside useEffect with CRA, React Testing Library and Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am having an issue mocking a returned `Promise` using:

- Create React app
- Jest
- RTL

I have a file:

```js
const books = [{
  id: 1,
  name: 'book'
}];

export const getBooks = () =>
  new Promise((res) => res(books));
```

I have a `useEffect` in my app:

```js
export const App = () => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await getBooks();
        setBooks(response);
      } catch (error) {
        setError("There seems to be an issue. Error:", error);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {books &&
        books.map((book) => {
          return (
            <li key={book.id}>
              {book.name}
            </li>
          );
        })
      }
    </div>
```

I have a test:

```js
import { App } from './App';
import { getBooks } from './books';

jest.mock('./books', () => ({
  getBooks: jest.fn(),
}));

getBlocks.mockReturnValue(() => Promise.resolve([{
  id: 1,
  name: 'mock book'
}]));

describe('App', () => {
  it('should render blocks', async () => {
    await render(<App />);
    expect(screen.getByText('mock book')).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

I just can't mock the return value! I can assert it's been called and I can console log the `getBooks` to see that it's mocked I just can't get any results. I also want to reject it so I can test the unhappy path but it won't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Few things:

1. You have a typo, it's not `getBlocks` but `getBooks`.
2. The `await` keyword is not necessary before rendering the component with `render`.
3. `getBooks` returns a promise that resolves with the value of `books`, yet when you're trying to mock it, you are making it return a **function** that returns a promise. Very different things.
4. You have to move the mocking to the test block in which it'll be used, or if you need this mocked value from `getBooks` on each one of your tests, you can move it inside a `beforeEach` hook. You can always override it for a specific test in which you are testing some edge case (e.g. an exception being thrown by the function, A.K.A "Unhappy path").
5. On the component's first render, `books` will be `undefined`, so you need to wait for the state to be updated. `getByText` query won't work, since it will immediately throw an error because it won't find the text you're expecting. You need to use the `findByText` query for this. It returns a promise that resolves when an element that matches the given query is found and rejects if the element is not found after the default timeout of 1000ms.
6. Since `getBooks` returns a promise, it makes more sense to use `mockResolvedValue` instead of `mockReturnValue`.

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react"
import { App } from "./App"
import { getBooks } from "./books"

jest.mock("./books", () => ({
  getBooks: jest.fn()
}))

describe("App", () => {
  it("should render blocks", async () => {
    getBooks.mockResolvedValueOnce([{ id: 1, name: "mock book" }])

    render(<App />)
    expect(await screen.findByText("mock book")).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```js
jest.mock('./books', () => ({
  getBooks: jest.fn().mockReturnValue(() => Promise.resolve([{
    id: 1,
    name: 'mock book'
  }]));
}));
```